# Json data is not updated in uitableview ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, afnetworking

I’ building an iOS article reading app using storyboards.I’m using AFNetworking library to parse json in the table view.

I am facing an problem that updated articles are not displaying in the table view means if in json new articles are added but not updated in my table view.

Here is my code:

```
       - (void)viewDidLoad
          {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
             x=2;

              tempJson = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
              [self.tableView reloadData];


       NSString *jsonLink=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cccccc.com/json.php?token=hashg156349&page=1"];
       NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:jsonLink];
       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                     timeoutInterval:30.0];
         [request setTimeoutInterval:120];


       AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

       [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

         NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray) {
                Json *json = [[Json alloc] initWithDictionary:dic];
                [tempJson addObject:json];
            }
            self.jsons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempJson];
            //  tempNinjas = nil;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190/255.0 green:190/255.0 blue:190/255.0 alpha:1.0];

               });
           });
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[error  localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
              [alertView show];
            }];
          [operation start];

            }
```

Comment: Can you show us your TableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: this code only runs once when this view is created (viewDidLoad), you would probably want to update the data every time the view is displayed (viewDidAppear) or even more often if the user can refresh the data with a pull-down to refresh action

Comment: thanks @dirgroten yeaa i want to update the data every time the view is displayed.

Comment: is better using this code in viewWillAppear every time you tap on a tableview is reloader or leave this code in to ViewDidLoad and under viewWillAppear usin [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: @ShashankBohra this doesn't resolve your issue. It seems that the data source is not setted to be the self.json array.

Comment: If you are sure that the data is correctly loaded after the `self.jsons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempJson];` ensure that the **DataSource is really connected to the `self.json` array**

Answer (score 0):

first try to call your data from server and  fetch the data . after that load your table view with your fetched data like this.

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear{



                 x=2;

                  tempJson = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


           NSString *jsonLink=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://cccccc.com/json.php?token=hashg156349&page=1"];
           NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:jsonLink];
           NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];
             [request setTimeoutInterval:120];


           AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

           [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

             NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray) {
                    Json *json = [[Json alloc] initWithDictionary:dic];
                    [tempJson addObject:json];
                }
                self.jsons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempJson];
                //  tempNinjas = nil;

                self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190/255.0 green:190/255.0 blue:190/255.0 alpha:1.0];

                   });
               });
              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:[error  localizedDescription]
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
                  [alertView show];
                }];
              [operation start];


    [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
```

Comment: Why this is supposed to solve the issue? He says that the data is correctly loaded in the array when the reloadData is called.

Comment: i think  self.jsons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempJson]; is not updated . because its call only one time . so he can  again fetch data and try

Comment: @Sport I did that also in -(void)viewWillAppear but its not working.what i'm figuring that it loads the cache data in uitableview but not the updated data.

Comment: have you checked inside viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear same data . please use the break point and check and what is tempJson and self.jsons

Comment: yes i have checked i thin its a AFNetworking cache policy issue

Comment: data is image or what